# Parse.com becomeInBackground Invalid Session Token

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am trying to logout from the current user. Login as another user, delete that user. Come back to the original user. This is what I have so far... It works fine, except it does not log back in the original user... It says Invalid Session Token. But this session token was retrieved using `currentUser.getSessionToken()` How could it be invalid??

PS: I have enabled the session on parse dashboard and in the app:

```
    ParseUser.enableRevocableSessionInBackground();
```

Code:

```
ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();


final String sessionToken = currentUser.getSessionToken();
Log.d(TAG, currentUser.getObjectId() + "  sessionToken: " + sessionToken);

ParseUser.logOut();
ParseUser.logInInBackground(userTest, passTest, new LogInCallback() {

    @Override
    public void done(final ParseUser onlineUser, ParseException e) {
        if ((e == null) && (onlineUser != null)) {


            Log.d(TAG, "onlineUser.deleteInBackground...");

            onlineUser.deleteInBackground(new DeleteCallback() {

                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {

                        Log.d(TAG, "onlineUser.deleted!");
                        ParseUser.logOut();
                        ParseUser.becomeInBackground(sessionToken, new LogInCallback() {@Override
                            public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {

                                if ((e == null) && (user !=null)){
                                    Log.d(TAG, "user retrieved...");
                                } else {

                                    Log.d(TAG, "user failed to be retrieved...");
                                    if (e != null) Log.d(TAG, "ParseUser.becomeInBackground ERROR: " + e.toString());
                                }
                            });
                        }

                    }
                });
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: with sessionToken defined "final" now way your user switch can work the way u want??

Comment: sessionToken is a String. I don't see how declaring it as final can affect the flow. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: when flipping state on currentUser with just one, "final" property for sessionToken cant be what u want ....

Comment: I have the same problem, i think it's Parse API bug.

Comment: I think when you call ParseUser.logOut() the session token is invalidated.